# How to enable loggingDebug for request scoped component?

Tags: atg, atg-dynamo, atg-droplet

How to make `loggingDebug = "true"` for a request scoped component in /dyn/admin ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this via `/dyn/admin` as the component is by its nature request scoped. What you can do is edit the component's properties file and it will pick this up for the next request.

Comment: We cannot do the same for upper environments like QA and production right?

Comment: It depends. Do you have an exploded `EAR`? What about a configured `ATG-Data` folder?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can actually do that.
go the dyn/admin/nucleus/ and add the path after the nucleus.

check this link
https://community.oracle.com/thread/2444056

so basically say I have the properties file in atg/userprofiling/myPropertiesFile.properties then just type
http://localhost:port/dyn/admin/nucleus/atg/userprofiling/myPropertiesFile

HIH

Answer (score 0):

First you have to define a global component with a loggingDebug property.

Example:

**LoggingConfiguration.properties**

```
$class=com.example.configuration.LoggingConfiguration
$scope=global

loggingDebug=false
```

Now in your request scoped component, link the loggingDebug property to LoggingConfiguration.loggingDebug as follows:

```
loggingDebug^=/path/LoggingConfiguration.loggingDebug
```

So you can control the loggingDebug configuration from the dyn/admin using the property in global scoped component LoggingConfiguration.

Once the LoggingConfiguration.loggingDebug is set to true, you will have logging enabled in further requests.